# Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using VS2015 EF6 Code First. I've used the power tools to generate a read-only model so that I can see how EF is interpreting my POCOs

It has come up with this, which looks ok to me:

[image]

My problem is when I run update-database to try and seed the data. Here is the migration code:

```
public partial class First : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                "dbo.Column",
                c => new
                    {
                        ColumnId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        ViewId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                        Heading = c.String(maxLength: 20),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ColumnId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.View", t => t.ViewId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.ViewId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.View",
                c => new
                    {
                        ViewId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Name = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.ViewId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.User",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        AdLogonDomain = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                        AdLogonId = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserId);

            CreateTable(
                "dbo.UserViewColumn",
                c => new
                    {
                        UserViewColumnId = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                        Column_ColumnId = c.Int(),
                        User_UserId = c.Int(),
                        View_ViewId = c.Int(),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.UserViewColumnId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.Column", t => t.Column_ColumnId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.User_UserId)
                .ForeignKey("dbo.View", t => t.View_ViewId)
                .Index(t => t.Column_ColumnId)
                .Index(t => t.User_UserId)
                .Index(t => t.View_ViewId);

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserViewColumn", "View_ViewId", "dbo.View");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserViewColumn", "User_UserId", "dbo.User");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.UserViewColumn", "Column_ColumnId", "dbo.Column");
            DropForeignKey("dbo.Column", "ViewId", "dbo.View");
            DropIndex("dbo.UserViewColumn", new[] { "View_ViewId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.UserViewColumn", new[] { "User_UserId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.UserViewColumn", new[] { "Column_ColumnId" });
            DropIndex("dbo.Column", new[] { "ViewId" });
            DropTable("dbo.UserViewColumn");
            DropTable("dbo.User");
            DropTable("dbo.View");
            DropTable("dbo.Column");
        }
    }
```

And here is my seed method:

```
protected override void Seed(TVS.ESB.BamPortal.DataLayer.UserPrefsContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            context.UserRecs.AddOrUpdate(
              u => u.AdLogonId,
              new User { AdLogonDomain = "dom", AdLogonId = "logon" }
            );

            View erpView = new View()
            {
                Name = "erp"
            };

            View cceView = new View()
            {
                Name = "cce"
            };

            context.ViewRecs.AddOrUpdate(
              v => v.Name,
              erpView, cceView
            );

            context.ColumnRecs.AddOrUpdate(
              v => v.Heading,
              new Column { ViewId = erpView.ViewId, Heading = "ErpColumn1" },
              new Column { ViewId = erpView.ViewId, Heading = "ErpColumn2" },
              new Column { ViewId = cceView.ViewId, Heading = "CceColumn1" },
              new Column { ViewId = cceView.ViewId, Heading = "CceColumn2" }
            );

        }
```

The POCO for the Column is as follows: note, I've had to comment out the navigation prop back to View else I get a circular reference error:

```
public class Column
    {
        public int ColumnId { get; set; }
        public int ViewId { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        // with the following navigation 
        //prop I get the error: Circular reference detected exception while serializing object to JSON
        //public virtual View View { get; set; }
    }
```

On executing update-database from the PMC and the seed method is run, I get the following error:

Unable to determine the principal end of the 'TVS.ESB.BamPortal.DataLayer.View_Columns' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

Anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: That still looks circular. Literally. Can you eliminate the UserViewColumn to Column relationship (or view to column) ?

Comment: Reverse engineering would have produced some fluent code. What does that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that I had ViewId in the column table as a foregin key to the View table. When I deleted this and instead used a navigation property of *public virtual View View { get; set; }* then it worked ok.

Here's the new model:

[image]

After I made this change then I no longer received the error *"Unable to determine the principal end of the relationship"* However, I did receive an error about being unable to deserialize JSON due to a circular error. I was able to solve that removing the explicit Navigation property *(public virtual List Columns { get; set;})* of Columns from the View table